# rclpy.Subscription getting the number of connections

Tags: ros, ros2, rclpy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to get the number of connections from a rclpy.Subscription object?
(In ROS1 we had  "subscriber.get_num_connections()")

If it is not possible, what is the alternative?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/373741/rclpy.subscription-getting-the-number-of-connections/) by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2982 on 2021-03-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`self._my_pub.get_subscription_count()`

See https://docs.ros2.org/foxy/api/rclpy/api/topics.html

---

Originally posted by [clyde](https://answers.ros.org/users/28405/clyde/) with karma: 1247 on 2021-03-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Christian Rauch](https://answers.ros.org/users/28941/christian-rauch/) on 2023-08-03**:
This is providing the number of subscriptions for a `rclpy.publisher.Publisher` and not the number of publishers for a `rclpy.subscription.Subscription`.